# defer function if it's already running on statechange - js

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, history.js

I feel like the answer is out there but I don't know what to look up.  I've looked into `defer` and `promise` but I'm not sure how to apply that if I want it to apply to itself.

If `update_content()` is running, I don't want it to be called again until it's finished the first time.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {

    var event_state = History.getState();

    // bad pseudo code
    if(update_content() is running, wait till it is finished(function() { 
         update_content(event_state.data.html); 
    }

});
```

As you can see by my horrible pseudo code, I want it to wait to run update_content() if it's already running. As soon as it's done, it will run again.  It takes 1-3 seconds to complete from fadeIn/Outs etc, and I want each statechange to wait till the previous request is complete.

There is no AJAX, by the way.  I want it to be synchronous in that sense.

**How do I delay a function from running until its done running?**

Here is the `update_content()` code:

```
// this function updates page content with ajax and cool effects!
function update_content(data) {
    if(data == null) return;

var id = $(data).prop('id'),
    content = "#" + id,
    header = 0;

    // if the header is full, header = 0.  if it's tiny, header = 1
    if($('#navbar.affix').length) { header = 1; }

    // if the page that needs to be loaded is NOT on the page
    // this could be #main, #content, etc
    if(!$(content).length) {
        $(data).hide().appendTo('#main_wrapper');       
    }

    // show the homepage $('#main')
    // fades the content viewer out. no positioning is done on the homepage.
    if(id == "main") {

        if(header == 1) { $('body, html').scrollTop(55); } else { window.scrollTo(0,0); }

        $('#main').siblings(':visible').center(header); // puts visible content on TOP of page

        $('#main')// /.center(header)
            .show();  // home page goes behind content
        $('#main').siblings().fadeOut(600, function() { // fadeout content overlay, and ON COMPLETE
                $(this).hide(); // hide that shit               
            });
        if(header == 1) { $('body, html').scrollTop(55); } else { window.scrollTo(0,0); }

        return;

}

    // show the content viewer $('#content')
    // fades content viewer in
    if(id = "content") {

        $('#content')
            .center(header) // place on top and center
            .fadeIn(function() { // fade in, and ON COMPLETE
                $('#main').hide(); // quickly remove siblings - DO NOT USE FADE
                $(this).uncenter(); // places it static so it is normal

                if(header == 1) { $('body, html').scrollTop(55); } else { window.scrollTo(0,0); }
        }); 

        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: The general answer to your question is that you hook into some sort of event that is triggered when the other operation is done and when that trigger happens, you start the next operation.  For the specifics of how to do that, I think you'll have to show us the `update_content()` code so we have some idea how to know when it's done or when it's operating.  Also, do you process every `statechange` event (e.g. save them in a queue if `update_content()` is still going) or do you just need to process the most recent one?

Comment: @jfriend00 I was hoping to queue them, but I don't know how to do that.  I didn't think the `update_content()` code would matter, although I feel like I might need to return a complete, or something, in it

Comment: A solution has to know when `update_content()` is done and how to trigger the next queued item when it's done.  We will need the `udpate_content()` to advise you on that key part of the solution.  Assuming it's a series of asynchronous operations (like fades), it is not as simple as just returning a value from it as the asynchronous operations will complete sometime later after the function itself finishes.  We need to see that code to know how to track when it's done.  A queue is not hard once we know how to know when `update_content()` is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the code for that function, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know when `update_content()` is done.  For that you can use some promises on your two animations and return a promise that is resolved when any animations started in this function are done (which could be immediately resolved if no animations are started):

```
// this function updates page content with ajax and cool effects!
// it returns a promise that is resolved when any animations started in this
// function are done
var updateRunning = 0;
function update_content(data) {
    if(data == null) [
        // return an already resolved promise
        return $().promise();
    }

    ++updateRunning;

    var id = $(data).prop('id'),
    content = "#" + id,
    header = 0, p1, p2;

    // if the header is full, header = 0.  if it's tiny, header = 1
    if($('#navbar.affix').length) { header = 1; }

    // if the page that needs to be loaded is NOT on the page
    // this could be #main, #content, etc
    if(!$(content).length) {
        $(data).hide().appendTo('#main_wrapper');       
    }

    // show the homepage $('#main')
    // fades the content viewer out. no positioning is done on the homepage.
    if(id == "main") {

        if(header == 1) { $('body, html').scrollTop(55); } else { window.scrollTo(0,0); }

        $('#main').siblings(':visible').center(header); // puts visible content on TOP of page

        $('#main')// /.center(header)
            .show();  // home page goes behind content
        p1 = $('#main').siblings().fadeOut(600, function() { // fadeout content overlay, and ON COMPLETE
                $(this).hide(); // hide that shit               
            }).promise();
        if(header == 1) { $('body, html').scrollTop(55); } else { window.scrollTo(0,0); }


    } else {

        // show the content viewer $('#content')
        // fades content viewer in
        if(id == "content") {

            p2 = $('#content')
                .center(header) // place on top and center
                .fadeIn(function() { // fade in, and ON COMPLETE
                    $('#main').hide(); // quickly remove siblings - DO NOT USE FADE
                    $(this).uncenter(); // places it static so it is normal

                    if(header == 1) { 
                        $('body, html').scrollTop(55); 
                    } else { 
                        window.scrollTo(0,0); 
                    }
            }).promise(); 

    }
    // note that either p1, p2 or both might be undefined here, but
    // $.when() should still work for us
    return $.when(p1, p2).always(function() {
        --updateRunning;
    });
}
```

FYI, I also changed `if (id = "content")` to `if (id == "content")` because I think what you had was a coding mistake.

Then, create a queue and a wrapper for `update_content()` that you call instead of `update_content` and the idea with this wrapper is that whenever `update_content()` finishes, it processes the next queued item.  You can tell if `update_content()` is running by maintaining a flag.

```
var queue = [];
function update_content_wrapper(data) {
    if (updateRunning !== 0) {
        // just queue the data if update already running
        queue.push(data);
    } else {
         update_content(data).always(function() {
             // if items in the queue, get the oldest one
             if (queue.length) {
                 update_content_wrapper(queue.shift());
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Then, you can just call the wrapper function on your statechange event and it will do all the dirty work for you:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    var event_state = History.getState();
    update_content_wrapper(event_state.data.html);
});
```

Anywhere else you were calling `update_content()`, you should switch it to calling `update_content_wrapper()`.

Comment: wow, amazing, perfect.  It worked flawlessly on first run and queued up the task.  you are amazing and a great jfriend!!